# Can't install software - setup not loading

Tags: windows-installer

I'm running Windows XP SP3, and I'm trying to install either Coffee Cup HTML Editor, or HTML-Kit.  Double-clicking either setup file produces no installer GUI.  They both in appear in Task Manager but do nothing else.  I have more than 30GB of free space on C:

To other annoying things are: MS Paint will not close, and after Computer Management loads it freezes.  I can't end mmc.exe either.

When I open Services.msc, I receive the error:

> One or more ActiveX controls could not be displayed because either:
>
> 1) Your current security settings prohibit running ActiveX controls on this page, or
>   2) You have blocked a publisher of one of the controls.
>
> As a result, the page might not display correctly.

I can't close Services either.  I wanted to restart Windows Installer.

Avast Antivirus control centre freezes after opening also.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? (Serious suggestion.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprise, rebooting fixed it.  I've only been using Windows for 17 years.

Comment: +1, That is the first thing to do in Windows, it cures so many problems, I had to reboot systems twice many times to get it to resolve a problem.